# Writing bytes of size_t to binary file

Tags: c++

```
size_t x = 123;

std::ofstream myFile("myfile.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>( &static_cast<uint64_t>(x) ),8); 

myFile.close()
```

I want to write the bytes of a `size_t` to a file by first promoting it to an unsigned 64 bit.  The above illusrates what I want to do, but doesn't work.  Can I do this without assigning a temporary value for x?

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? Compile error? Garbage data? Nothing written to file?

Comment: No, you cannot take an address of a temporary.

Comment: Sadly (or not), C++ does not have compound literals. You need to have a variable.

Comment: This site uses a Question and Answer format. Answers go in the Answer boxes; please do not edit the question to contain an answer. Instead you can accept one of the posted answers; or post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't take the address of a temporary. For convenience, I would probably make a function for this. Using a function means you create a parameter and you **can** take the address of a parameter.

Something a bit like this:

```
template<typename POD>
std::ostream& write_pod(std::ostream& os, POD const& pod)
{
    // make sure we're not trying to write a complex object this way
    static_assert(std::is_pod<POD>::value, "must be plain old data");

    return os.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(pod), sizeof(pod));
}

int main()
{
    std::size_t x = 123;

    std::ofstream myFile("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary);

    write_pod(myFile, std::uint64_t(x));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Why do you return the output stream rather than just returning void?

Comment: @thc It is a common pattern when using streams. It follows the form used by `std::getline` for example. It allows you to test the return condition of the stream to make sure the reading/writing succeeded, especially in a loop. Also it allows you to write *compound* input/output statements that can be expressive. If you notice the `myFile.write()` function that you used does the same thing, it returns the stream.

Comment: @thc All the output (and input) functions of stream objects return a reference to the stream: [std::ofstream::write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) for example. Also [std::ofstream::put](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put). And all of the [insertion operators <<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

Answer (score 4):

You probably want something like:

```
uint64_t u64 = x;
myfile.write ((const char *) &u64, sizeof (u64));
```

You can't get away without assigning x to a temporary, but then again, why is that a problem?

Comment: Thanks.  It's not so much a problem, it's just that I have to do it a lot, and I dislike having temporary variables.

Comment: Would you mind to replacing `8` with `sizeof(u64)` ?

Comment: @Christophe Done

Comment: @thc Put the code in a (small, inline) function then.

Comment: @PaulSanders here's what I have.  Look good?  `inline void writeSizeToFile8(std::ofstream & myFile, size_t x) {uint64_t x_temp = static_cast<uint64_t>(x); myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x_temp),8);}`

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding to it via comments please.

Comment: Seems too complicated.  You don't need a cast when assigning to `x_temp`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the question could be edited to contain further information that clarifies the question -- not to contain proposed answers

Comment: @M.M Ok, I read it like something that could have been tried out by OP, failed and then added to the question.